# Why does my while loop not work in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

The result is initialized as 0 but after the while loop is executed its value still remains 0. I tried a lot and it doesn't work as I expect. I don't know whether it is because of the variable declarations.

```
armstrongNumber = (num) -> 
  originalnum = num

  result=0
  count=0
  while num != 0
     num = parseInt(num / 10)
     count++

  while num != 0
     remainder = num % 10
     result += Math.pow(remainder, count)
     num = parseInt(num / 10)


  console.log result
  console.log count
  console.log num

  if result == originalnum
     console.log "Yes, it is an Armstrong number"
  else
     console.log "It is not an Armstrong number"


armstrongNumber 12
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: The value of result remains 0 even after the execution of while loop.

Comment: The second loop will never run (and that is the only loop where result is touched). The first loop makes sure that num == 0. The second loop only runs when num != 0 which can never be the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the error and my code is working now.

Comment: Maybe you could post your correct code and then mark the question as resolved? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
armstrongNumber = (num) -> 
  originalnum = num
  reoriginalnum=num

  result=0
  count=0

  #find the number of digits in a number
  while num != 0
    num = parseInt(num / 10)
    count++

  while reoriginalnum != 0
    remainder = reoriginalnum % 10
    result += Math.pow(remainder, count) 
#Math function pow to find the power of remainder
    reoriginalnum = parseInt(reoriginalnum / 10)

  if result == originalnum    #verify the number is armstrong or not
    console.log "Yes, it is an armstrong number"
  else
    console.log "It is not an armstrong number"

    #call the function to check: armstrongNumber 1634
```

Comment: This is the correct code. I assigned num value to two variables originalnum and reoriginalnum as value of num was getting lost after while loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.